# JavaScript dynamically create and populate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically create array varaible based on the attribute from another array. Sample data:

```
var arr = [{category: 'bill', date: '2017/04/29', total: 35049.48999999998},
{category: 'bill', date: '2017/05/12', total: 249.03},
{category: 'bill', date: '2017/11/05', total: 568.5499999999998},
{category: 'electrical appliance', date: '2017/08/09', total: 3930.76},
{category: 'electrical appliance', date: '2017/03/28', total: 532.1},
{category: 'food', date: '2017/08/09', total: 639.05},
{category: 'food', date: '2017/08/31', total: 2653.05}];
```

What I am trying to achieve is, I wanted to create an array for each of the category then pass the dynamically created array as parameter into another function.

The reason I am doing this is because I wanted to calculate the total amount of last week and this week spend for each of the category and display them at different section.

For instance, this week spend for food is 639.05, last week spend for food is 2653.05. This week spend for electrical appliance is 3930.76 etc.

What I really unsure about is how to GROUP the category as one temporary variable, then pass the temporary variable to another function for me to calculate the spend for this/last week.

I already have a function to calculate the spend for this/last week and it is working perfectly, the parameter for that function is an array, in this case, I am trying to GROUP the category together then pass it separately rather than simply pass the array with all category to perform the calculation.

How can I actually achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: please add an example of the wanted result, and what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide the exact structure of the data you want as output. Also provide the code for the function that is supposed to process this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for grouping and for iterating the groups, you could take the keys of the object and iterate over them.

```js
var array = [{ category: 'bill', date: '2017/04/29', total: 35049.48999999998 }, { category: 'bill', date: '2017/05/12', total: 249.03 }, { category: 'bill', date: '2017/11/05', total: 568.5499999999998 }, { category: 'electrical appliance', date: '2017/08/09', total: 3930.76 }, { category: 'electrical appliance', date: '2017/03/28', total: 532.1 }, { category: 'food', date: '2017/08/09', total: 639.05 }, { category: 'food', date: '2017/08/31', total: 2653.05 }],
    groups = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function (o) {
    groups[o.category] = groups[o.category] || [];
    groups[o.category].push(o);
});

console.log(groups.food); // just food
console.log(groups);

// iterate keys of groups and some values
Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (k) {
    groups[k].forEach(function (o) {
        console.log(k, o.date);
    });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For accessing a single known category, you could use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like

> ```
> groups.food                    // dot notation
> groups['electrical appliance'] // bracket notation
> ```

Comment: Cool but in this case, how can I actually access the record under food category and store them as temporary array?

Comment: just take an accessor and store the result.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to access the date and total under each category rather than the total of the entire category, I just groups.food.total?

Comment: you need to get the total first by a category.

Comment: Hey how can I loop thru the groups? Assumed that I do not know what type of categories are there so I could not simple access groups.food or groups.bill like that, but rather, I have to loop thru groups to get the category name one by one and pass as parameter to another function. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting the keys and for iterating with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I tried to do this: groups.forEach(function (o) {
  console.log(Object.keys(o));
 }); But it told me Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: groups.forEach is not a function

Comment: I made some twist from the solution to achieve what I wanted. It works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to firstly transform the array to an object that the key gonna be the category name, and the value an array of all the expanses for the category.

After that, you will be able to apply your logic to it.

```js
var arr = [{
    category: 'bill',
    date: '2017/04/29',
    total: 35049.48999999998
  },
  {
    category: 'bill',
    date: '2017/05/12',
    total: 249.03
  },
  {
    category: 'bill',
    date: '2017/11/05',
    total: 568.5499999999998
  },
  {
    category: 'electrical appliance',
    date: '2017/11/27',
    total: 3930.76
  },
  {
    category: 'electrical appliance',
    date: '2017/03/28',
    total: 532.1
  },
  {
    category: 'food',
    date: '2017/03/10',
    total: 639.05
  },
  {
    category: 'food',
    date: '2017/06/22',
    total: 2653.05
  }
];

const obj = arr.reduce((result, current) => {
  result[current.category] = result[current.category] || {
    cats: [],
    total: 0
  };
  result[current.category].cats.push(current);
  result[current.category].total += current.total; // some logic
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Cool but in this case, how can I actually access the record under food category and store them as temporary array?

Comment: @guest176969, why store as temporary array when you already have it under the form `result.food`? Don't unnecessarily copy into variables. Just use `result.food`, `result['electrical appliance']` and `result.bill` where you need them.

Comment: @FelixMosheev Let's say I wanted to access the date and total under each category rather than the total of the entire category, I just result.food.total?

Comment: The `//Some logic` line was only for demonstration, there you can do whatever logic you want.
At that line you have the aggregated data of the category + the current item in the original array.